# new ethers.provider.web3provider is not returning anything?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js

I am this in my transactionContext.jsx file,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {BrowserProvider,ethers} from "ethers";
import { contractABI, contractAddr } from '../utils/constants';

const {ethereum} = window;

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();

 const getEthereumContract = () => {
    console.log("get contract start");
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    console.log(provider);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddr, contractABI, 
signer);

console.log(provider,signer,transactionsContract);
};

// code ...
```

I am creating a react context which I will pass to my other components. But the problem is, `const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);` is simply not working. It's like the execution just stops after it reaches this line. I know this because the "start" log is getting printed but thats just it. No errors, no exceptions, it just stops after that. I tried searching online, but didn't find a single issue regarding this. So what is going on here? What have I messed up?

Do ask if more context or code samples are needed.

Comment: Found the problem. I had installed the latest ethers@6.0.8 which apparently has a different api(providers) than the previous version. I downgraded it, and its working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes indeed,
ethers v6 has now this:

```
// v5
provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

// v6:
provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
```

BrowserProvider replaces `providers.Web3Provider`

source: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-contracts